# Hiding your left sidebar leaves some left

Tags: bug, preferences, left-nav, site-settings

The user profile setting to hide the left sidebar doesn't completely hide it:

Settings:

> "Hide left navigation -
> When you flip this switch, the left navigation will no longer be pinned to the left of the page on Q&A sites."

It makes it 2/3rds smaller, but doesn't completely remove it. This worked correctly a few months ago.

> [image]

Reproduced on:

- Chrome Android (Desktop view): 108.0.5359.79
- Firefox Android (Desktop view): 108.0b6 (Build #2015919115), 77de6a012+

Comment: No repro with Chrome latest and Windows 10, it's totally hidden when I choose to hide it. Please add browser/OS info to the post, and also this might be result of rogue userscript, try to disable all of them and reload, the sidebar might vanish.

Comment: Thanks @Sha, added two browser versions. No plugins / userscripts.

Comment: @Sha, are you a Team member a beta tester, or a collective member for the Staging Ground on Stack Overflow?, maybe that's the hangup. https://i.stack.imgur.com/veFqY.png

Comment: Good point. I'm none of those. So likely one of them breaks the side bar hiding preference indeed.

Comment: @Dev, this seems to have resolved itself; I did clear my cookies, log out and back in again.